# QuForms(iphorm) + Wordpress + Google App engine. (File uploads)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, wordpress

I have a wordpress website hosted in google app engine. I am using the popular form service (QuForms) as a wordpress plugin. However, due to the file write restrictions, I am unable to use the file upload service.

I have tried tinkering with the 'temp' variables in the hope of making this work, but I am unsure.

Can anybody give any tips/guidance to make file upload possible in google app engine ?

Link to the [common.php](http://pastebin.com/4ekbkiK1) (which I believe is responsible for the file uploads).

I have created a bucket. I have also tried using

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'my_bucket' ];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options);
```

to create a 'temp' url, as told by google. But even then this script fails.

Comment: I think the upload part is actually in the file "IPHORM_INCLUDES_DIR . '/form.php'"

Comment: I have another question. When I create a url using CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options); and submit the form, will ONLY the $_FILES global variable be posted ?
or will other form data be posted as well ?

Comment: all the data if it's multipart/form-data

Comment: so I can access the other variables from $_POST[] ?

Comment: another thing. How did you know the upload part is in form.php ? 
have you checked it ? 
And I am still in the dark about getting the file uploads to work with GAE :/ . What can I do ?

Comment: no i looked at the code you put in pastebin and took a guess, as I don't have the plugin source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68252/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-stuart-langley).